# Finding Element in ext JS from WebDriver (From C# code)

Tags: extjs, selenium-webdriver

This is the below Extjs code for my webpage

```
<div id="dataViewPanel" class="x-panel">
      <div id="ext-gen76" class="x-panel-header x-unselectable" style="-moz-user-select: none;">
           <div id="ext-gen168" class="x-tool x-tool-refresh "> </div>
           <div id="ext-gen164" class="x-tool x-tool-add " style="position: relative;">
           <div id="ext-gen189" class=""></div>
       </div>
    <div id="ext-gen160" class="x-tool x-tool-edit x-item-disabled " style="position: relative;">
           <div id="ext-gen188" class=""></div>
       </div>
```

When I search with below command in the Firefox console, I can locate the correct output

```
window.frames['abFrame'].contentDocument.getElementById('dataViewPanel').childNodes[0].childNodes[1]
```

As I am new to handling of ext.js objects in Web-driver, I am unable to locate the element with class="x-tool x-tool-add and unable to click on this.

Could any one please help me with this.

Comment: There is nothing to do with the JavaScript framework you use. Finally everything you are going to work on with your automation framework is on HTML tags and its attributes. So i feel there may be some spell or space or typo mistakes in the class name you mentioned in your web driver.

Comment: I tried this code:                           IEdriver.FindElement(By.Id("dataViewPanel")).FindElement(By.CssSelector(".x-panel-header.x-unselectable")).FindElement(By.CssSelector(".x-tool.x-tool-add ")).Click();                                                                   and ending up with the element not found

Comment: `IEdriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#dataViewPanel .x-panel-header .x-tool-add"))` is a simpler way to navigate to your element. The selectors are correct - if this doesn't work there must be some other issue that is not apparent in this example. Perhaps your code is in an iframe and you need selenium to navigate to this iframe first? (I'm just guessing on your use of window.frames)